# How is the code from the IOCCC contest submissions shaped / indented?

Tags: indentation

Some, if not most, of the code submissions sent to [IOCCC](https://www.ioccc.org) are indented / "shaped". Examples:

- https://www.ioccc.org/2018/vokes/prog.c
- https://www.ioccc.org/2018/yang/prog.c
- https://www.ioccc.org/2018/poikola/prog.c
- https://github.com/mame/quine-relay/blob/master/QR.rb

How is the code of all these submissions formatted / shaped? Is it done by hand? Or is there some tool / way of automating the "shaping" of a given chunk of code?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help as I'm a three time winner. The answer is it varies. I tend to do it manually (in vim typically with format options disabled as not doing this can cause strange problems). However Yusuke Endoh (that's mame who you linked to) at least sometimes does it programmatically.

In [2020/endoh2](https://www.ioccc.org/2020/endoh2/prog.c) he included a password protected zip file (password is referred to in the hint file - see below on hints though). When you extract it you'll see how he did it. As expected with him he used Ruby.

I suspect there are other ways as well. Some winners have had to write their own CPP and other tools that help with formatting / other things.

As for the hint files: they'll be changed to README.md files.